# Atmel AVR ADC Inconsistent Sampling Time

Tags: adc, avr, atmel

I'm running an ATMega1284 at 20MHz. I've set the ADC up in free running mode as such:

```
void SetupADCInFreeRunningMode(uint16_t ref, uint16_t channel, uint16_t leftAdjust, uint16_t clockDiv)
{
    ADMUX |= ref | leftAdjust | channel;
    DIDR0 |= true << ADC3D;
    ADCSRA |= true << ADEN | true << ADATE | true << ADIE | clockDiv;
}
```

And I'm sampling the ADC into a buffer in the ADC interrupt:

```
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    DISABLE_INT;
    ToggleLed(Red);
    if (BufferPosition < ADC_BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        ADCBuffer[BufferPosition++] = ADCH - (int8_t)127;
    }
    else
    {
        BufferFull = true;
    }
    ENABLE_INT;
}
```

Since I'm having issues with my Goertzel implementation returning bad results I wanted to check my sample rate. Based on the simulator, this ought to be around 12019Hz.

However, after plugging my data analyzer into the LED pin being toggled, I find that it's sampling at an inconsistent speed, I get two samples at 12.4kHz followed by one sample at 9.9kHz. Given I disable the other interrupts whilst the sample is being taken, what could be  causing this?

---

In order to help debug this I removed everything except the LED toggle:

```
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    DISABLE_INT;
    ToggleLed(Red);
    ENABLE_INT;
}
```

Now I get a consistent (all in us) 80 on, 80 off, 80 on, 80 off, 80 on, 100 off. Does the ADC have to reset every 6 interrupts or something?

---

`TIMER1_COMPA` was set to run at 200Hz. With this ISR:

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect,  ISR_NOBLOCK)
{
    PushFrame();
}
```

However, disabling this interrupt so the ADC interrupt is the only one on the system does not help.

---

With an absolutely minimal working example:

```
//Standard lib includes
#include <stdbool.h>

//AVR includes
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>

//Project includes
#include "leds.h"
#include "ADC.h"

//Named Literals
#define COMP_200Hz 12500 //NOTE: Needs 8x prescaler
#define F_CPU 20e6

//Macros
#define ENABLE_INT sei()
#define DISABLE_INT cli()

//Functions
int main(void)
{
    SetupADCInFreeRunningMode(AVCC, ADC3, LAEnabled, CDOneTwoEigth);
    ENABLE_INT;
    StartADC();
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (true)
    {
        ;
    }
}

ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    ToggleLed(Red);
}
```

For completeness:

```
void ToggleLed(Led colour)
{
    switch (colour)
    {
        case Red:
            PORTD ^= true << RED_LED;
            break;
        case Yellow:
            PORTD ^= true << YELLOW_LED;
            break;
        case Green:
            PORTD ^= true << GREEN_LED;
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is still occurring.

I'm really stumped on this one.

---

I've upped the sample rate on my logic analyser to 8MHz and now get this output.

[image: Oscilloscope]

So something strange is happening periodically.

Comment: Are there any other interrupts enabled?

Comment: There is: `TIMER1_COMPA_vect` but this should be disabled when handling the ADC interrupt as `DISABLE_INT` is `cli()` and `ENABLE_INT` is `sei()`

Comment: But those are inside the interrupt. Could another interrupt be blocking you from entering the interrupt in the first place?

Comment: Disabling interrupts **inside** the ADC handler prevents the ADC handler from being preempted once it has started executing. Does it prevent the ADC handler from running immediately if the timer handler is already running when the ADC interrupt occurs? I'm really asking, I don't know how interrupt priority is handled on an AVR.

Comment: That's probably it, I have another interrupt firing every 500us. Is there any way to allow the ADC interrupt to fire if it is triggered whilst the Timer1 ISR is being run?

Comment: I've just enabled nested interrupts as per instructions from here: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html and that hasn't helped

Comment: Disabling the timer interrupt completely has not helped

Comment: @Persistence AVRs disable the interrupts when entering an ISR, and then renable them on exit (compiler generated `reti` instruction). Do you have _any_ other interrupts enabled (timer aside)?

Comment: @awjlogan, no. It was just the ADC and the Timer interrupt.

Comment: @Persistence Can you post the whole code, rather than just the ISR, please.

Comment: @awjlogan this is the state it was in before I started making changes whilst working through this question. https://gitea.pyrosoftsolutions.co.uk/james/EE3AES-Advanced-Embedded-Systems/src/branch/master/Coursework/dtmf-decoder

Comment: @Persistence - from a very quick skim, I suspect that your `DoGoertzel` routine is taking too much time and not resetting the buffer flag (although that doesn't match the LED toggle test). Suggest making an absolute minimum program to test (no 7seg, no filer etc...). Your register setup looks correct.

Comment: @awjlogan I've added a minimal working example to the question

Comment: Does this ADC peripheral have any sort of automatic calibration?

Comment: @gregb212 not that I'm aware of... It's just the one built into the Atmel AVR

Comment: You said you have the adc prescalar enabled. The datasheet says it needs an input frequency between 50khz and 200khz. A normal conversion takes 13 clock cycles. What is the prescalar setting?

Comment: The prescaler is set to `CDOneTwoEighth` which is defined by `#define CDOneTwoEigth true << ADPS2 | true << ADPS1 | true << ADPS0` so the ADC frequency should be 156250 and the sample rate around 12019Hz. Which is for the most part what I'm seeing excluding the periodic weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

- The inconsistency isn't periodical as you say, looks more like random.
- ISV vector or compare have some limitations when a call is break by an incorrect memory assignment. I assume that is function from the Watchdog, but could that be random triggered with so little calls?
- One sample is periodically disappearing due probably a incorrect flag setting or a exited interrupt function during the ISR ON cycle.
- This may be due hardware interrupts may be triggered and stopped from the internal scheduler or a periodic bug in the MCU produced by the load itself.
- Eventually some inconsistent ISR timing setting may produce this kind of failure.